# Terminal program to log all system reosurces?

Tags: ram, cpu, monitor, log, gpu

I need log the graphs of

- CPU
- GPU
- RAM
- GPU vRAM
- Disk I/O

simultaneously on a system using a non-GUI program, so that I can analyze later. How can I do this?

I have an Nvidia K40 GPU

Answer (score 0):

You can use the terminal application `glances` in order to get the following information which you need :

- CPU
- RAM
- Disk I/O

As you need these values stored in some file, use the option `--export-csv FILENAME`. This should do the job for you.

As for the GPU information it sort of depends on what drivers you have installed. Something which works for me and can work for you as well is

`nvidia-smi -f FILENAME -l LOOP_TIME`

This stores the `nvidia-smi`'s output, which is the information you require, in the file name `FILENAME` at a frequency of `1/LOOP_TIME`. Although, since it stores in a human readable format parsing this might be cumbersome.

You can also explore the option `-x` coupled with `-q` with `nvidia-smi` to store in an xml format.